# cPanel email filter pipe to a program not executing

Tags: php, email, parsing, filter, cpanel

I can't get an Email Filter for a specific address to properly execute the script its being piped to, nothing happens.  No log message, no error message - I can't tell whats going on and why its not executing:

The filter (from: /home/myUser/ect/myDomain/register/filter):

```
headers charset "UTF-8"

if not first_delivery and error_message then finish endif

#Bounced Registrations
if
 $header_subject: contains "Message Delivery Failure"
then
 pipe "| php -q /home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmail.php"
endif
```

I have tried many combinations:

```
 pipe "| /home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmail.php"
 pipe "/home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmail.php"
 pipe "|php -q /home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmail.php"
 pipe "/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmail.php"
 pipe "| /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmail.php"
```

But the script runs cleanly from command when I feed a saved bounced email to the script - the below captures the bad email address and prints "Script Ran" to the log file :

```
[> email]$ cat badEmail.msg | php -q bouncedEmail.php
```

The script, set with permissions: 0755

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "bouncedEmails.log");
include '/home/myUser/dev/scripts/includes.php' ;

error_log("Script ran") ;

// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r") ;
$email = "" ;
while (!feof($fd)) {
  $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

// handle email
$lines = explode("\n", $email);

// empty vars
$splittingheaders = true;

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++){
  //if ($splittingheaders) {
    // this is a header
    $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";

    // look out for special headers
    if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        list($fName,$fAddy) = explode("<",$matches[1]) ;
        $fAddy = str_replace(">","",$fAddy) ;
        //error_log("FROM: " .$lines[$i],0) ;
        
    }
    if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        list($tName,$tAddy) = explode("<",$matches[1]) ;
        $tAddy = str_replace(">","",$tAddy) ;
        error_log("Bad Email: $tAddy",0) ;
        writeDB($tAddy) ;
    }
    if (preg_match("/^REFID: (.*)/",$lines[$i],$matches)) {
        $uid = $matches[1] ;
    }
  //}

  if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
    // empty line, header section has ended
    $splittingheaders = false;
  }
}


// update any DB records with matched email addresses
function writeDB($to) {
  $query = "UPDATE userTable SET user_email='',user_emailVerify=0 WHERE user_email=?" ;
  list($upCount,$upError) = dbUpdate($query,array($to)) ;
}

unset($pdo) ;
?>
```

So what am I doing wrong that is preventing the Email Filter script from executing?

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed but I don't know why my original script wasn't working.

`#!/usr/local/bin/php -q` wasn't being recognized even though the file had been given set to an executable with `chmod 0755 bouncedEmails.php`

So to get it work, in the `pipe to a program` I added:
`php -q /home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmails.php`

Answer (score -1):

3 steps to get email filter pipe to program to work

1. script.php: chmod 755
2. path in pipe to program: | php -q public_html/script.php
3. add #!/usr/local/bin/php -q at the top of script.php before the php opening tag <?php

Comment: Please edit your answer and use backticks to highlight your `code`, `commands` etc. to improve the readability.

Comment: Line #2 is incorrect according to cpanel "If the script requires an interpreter such as Perl or PHP, you should omit the /usr/bin/perl or /usr/bin/php portion. Make sure that your script is executable and has the appropriate target at the top of the script."  All you need is what you have in line #3